# Angular, how to make other elements false when one element is true

Tags: html, angular, boolean

i need help to make other elements condition's false when one element's condition is true and if it is possible only one that can be true at a time. I'm not sure what i wrote is correct. Can anyone help me, please?

```js
showProduct: boolean = false;
showCustomer: boolean = false;
showSupplier: boolean = false;

if (showProduct = true) {
  this.showCustomer = false;
  this.showSupplier = false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" (click)="showProduct=!showProduct"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="showCustomer=!showCustomer"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="showSupplier=!showSupplier"></a>

<div *ngIf="showProduct" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showCustomer" align="center">
  <app-customer></app-customer>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showSupplier" align="center">
  <app-supplier></app-supplier>
</div>
```

Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like :

```
(click)="showProduct=!showProduct;showCustomer=false;showSupplier=false;"
```

---

OR

> Component side :

```
showStatus = {
    showProduct : true;
    showCustomer : false;
    showSupplier : false;
}

changeShowStatus(changeBlock) {
    for(let block in this.showStatus) {
        if(block === changeBlock) {
            this.showStatus[block] = !this.showStatus[block];
        } else {
            this.showStatus[block] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Template side :

```
<a href="#" (click)="changeShowStatus('showProduct')"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="changeShowStatus('showCustomer')"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="changeShowStatus('showSupplier')"></a>


<div *ngIf="showStatus['showProduct']" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showStatus['showCustomer']" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showStatus['showSupplier']" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the logic of your code:

```js
<a href="#" (click)="show='product'">Show product</a>
<a href="#" (click)="show='customer'">Show customer</a>
<a href="#" (click)="show='supplier'">Show supplier</a>

<div *ngIf="show==='product'" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>

<div *ngIf="show==='customer'" align="center">
  <app-customer></app-customer>
</div>

<div *ngIf="show==='supplier'" align="center">
  <app-supplier></app-supplier>
</div>
```

In your component's class:

```
show: string = 'product';
```

Answer (score 1):

so something like this while creating a dummy object obj and mainobject mainObj to bind on the UI.

```
showProduct: boolean = false;
showCustomer: boolean = false;
showSupplier

mainObj = {};
obj = {
    showProduct: false,
    showCustomer: false,
    showSupplier: false 
}

<a href="#" (click)="updateObj('showProduct')"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="updateObj('showCustomer')"></a>
<a href="#" (click)="updateObj('showSupplier')"></a>

function updateObj(prope){
    mainObj = Object.assign(obj, mainObj);
    mainObj[prope] = true;
}

<div *ngIf="mainObj.showProduct" align="center">
  <app-product></app-product>
</div>

<div *ngIf="mainObj.showCustomer" align="center">
  <app-customer></app-customer>
</div>

<div *ngIf="mainObj.showSupplier" align="center">
  <app-supplier></app-supplier>
</div>
```

Comment: `angular.copy` is not available in angular v2+

Comment: @Lalit Sachdeva Use Object.assign

Comment: @Faly Thanks for notifying!